# Laravel Notification broadcast on pusher

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications, laravel-7, broadcasting

Need help with notification broadcast with pusher.

Getting these errors in the console.

pusher.min.js:8 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/pusher/auth 404 (Not Found)

pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 404

pusher.min.js:8 Pusher : No callbacks on private-App.User.2 for pusher:subscription_error

I need help with echo or any other way to subscribe to the private channel of pusher

This is my new-comment.js

```js
var commentNotificationsWrapper   = $('.dropdown-comment');
var commentNotificationsToggle    = commentNotificationsWrapper.find('a[data-toggle]');
var commentNotificationsCountElem = commentNotificationsToggle.find('i[comment-data-count]');
var commentNotificationsCount     = parseInt(commentNotificationsCountElem.data('comment-count'));
var commentNotifications          = commentNotificationsWrapper.find('ul.dropdown-menu');

if (commentNotificationsCount <= 0) {
//   commentNotificationsWrapper.hide();
}

// Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher  = new Pusher("5f53220af298e18653c8",{
  cluster: 'ap2' ,
  encrypted: true,
  auth: {
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      }
  }
});

// Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-App.User.'+userId);

// Bind a function to a Event (the full Laravel class)
channel.bind('Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', function(data) {
  var commentExistingNotifications = commentNotifications.html();
  var commentNewNotificationHtml = `
    <li class="notification active px-3">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
            <strong class="notification-title">`+data.message+`</strong>
            <!--p class="notification-desc">Extra description can go here</p-->
            <div class="notification-meta">
              <small class="timestamp">about a minute ago</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
  `;
  commentnotifications.html(commentNewNotificationHtml + commentExistingNotifications);
  commentNotificationsCount += 1;
  commentNotificationsCountElem.attr('comment-data-count', commentNotificationsCount);
  commentNotificationsWrapper.find('.comment-count').text(commentNotificationsCount);
  commentNotificationsWrapper.show();
});
```

Comment: let me see your routes

Comment: @DanielLogvin But i am calling the notify method from the controller

Comment: not going to answer this. Read the laravel docs.